# Keyboard layout identical to "US Extended" on Macbook Pro

Tags: keyboard-layout, macbook, macosx

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 on a Dell machine and I want to have the exact same keyboard layout as I have on my other machine, which is a Macbook Pro with an International English keyboard. On the Mac I have the keyboard set to **US Extended**.

On Ubuntu I have the layout set to **English (Macintosh)** which gives me this layout:
[image: English (Macintosh) layout on Ubuntu]

However what I really want is an exact copy of the **US Extended** on my Mac, which looks like this:

[image: US Extended layout on OSX]

And with the following modifiers with the alt key pressed:

[image: US Extended layout on OSX (alt key pressed)]

The layouts are similar but there are small differences, in particular producing the character ˙ modifier on Mac is Alt-w, while under Ubuntu it's Alt-h.
I've tried all the English layouts on Ubuntu but none match this exactly.
Any suggestions? I'm not adverse to writing a layout config myself, if that's what it takes, but a few pointers would be welcome!

Comment: You can experiment with this: http://rlog.rgtti.com/2014/05/01/how-to-modify-a-keyboard-layout-in-linux/ --- beware, it is an exercise in patience.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing for you is to learn the keyboards of each world ... because by using a pc keyboard on a mac or a mac keyboard on a pc you'll restrict yourself on the real use of the machine.

After a simple search those links answer to your question, you'll just have to apply it to your needs :

How to configure a keyboard on Ubuntu (simple way but may not fit your specific needs) :
http://rabbitmoondot.blogspot.fr/2012/01/how-to-configure-ubuntus-keyboard-to.html
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard

and the hard one (but the one that I think will answer to your need) : 
http://michal.kosmulski.org/computing/articles/custom-keyboard-layouts-xkb.html
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

John!

It looks like you'll need an edition of Kino's AltLatin ASDF Transliteration keyboard layout, which is based on Apple's United States Extended layout—albeit optimized primarily for input of Semitic language transliteration.  It was originally made by Kino, in association with the Middle East Documentation Center (Mamluk Studies Resources) at the University Of Chicago (whom also publishes their U-Chicago Press Style Manual)—but made for your Ubuntu system.

I'm currently working on building version 1.3 of the Windows AltLatin layout—which'll introduce some more deadkeys (for slashed, barred, and for hoi-marked Vietnamese letters; as well as for miscellaneous characters), and add support for Vietnamese and for Ancient Egyptian hieroglyphic transliteration.

You may contact me via e-mail:  [RWhlk142@gmail.com].  Thank You!

Robert Lloyd Wheelock
INTERNATIONAL SYMBOLISM RESEARCH INSTITUTE
Augusta / Harmony, ME  U.S.A.

Comment: This does not resolve the problem, use a comment in such case.